# Android : How to know the IP of connected phone to eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, adb

I know that when we use a virtual device for testing android applications, we have access to the machine with this IP : 10.0.2.2

But when I use a real hardware phone instead of a virtual one, I don't know how I can access to the machine?

Thanks for any help...

**NOTE** that currently I can run my applications on the connected phone.

Comment: your phone's "about" page will tell you your IP. settings -> about phone -> status

Comment: there is no IP in the About page. Of course i need the machine IP! not the phone's! :)

Comment: so... your pc's ip address? start -> run -> cmd -> "ipconfig". ON a mac? terminal -> "ifconfig".

Comment: u right. but in about page, the "Mobile network state" value is "disconnected"! :( My main problem is this

Comment: you probably wouldn't be able to connect to your PC anyways, since mobile networks are proxied via NAT, as would be your home pc. why don't you try using your local WiFi instead?

Comment: The functionality behind 10.0.2.2 is unique to emulators and not supported by physical devices.  There is no official way of doing this, though some forms of tethering may achieve a usable network connection over the USB cable as a *side effect*.

Comment: Thanks @Marc B . Unfortunately i have not wifi card on my my PC now! tnx anyway :)

Comment: easy enough to get a usb wifi adapter, or even a full-blown wifi AP and connect via that. Of course, if your phone hasn't been locked down, you COULD try using tethering-over-usb, which WOULD give you an ip address and a normal tcp link.

Comment: it seems i must buy a wifi card! :) it's more secure way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To connect through Wifi
Install connectify software in laptop to make a wifi hotspot. Then connect your phone to this hotspot.

You can find your local network's IP by go to cmd or press Winkey + R then type in "ipconfig". It will give out some information and your local IP should look like 192.168.1.x .

Using this IP you can connect to your local host from your phone

To connect through USB:
You should go for REVERSE TETHERING......
May be these links would help you.
http://www.orclage.com/connect-internet-pc-laptop-android-mobile-phone/

Comment: I use the phone via USB cable. I have a PC and unable to use Wifi :(

Comment: i know about Reverse Tethering, but the phone is not mine and i don't want to root it. Thanks anyway ;)